# URL Rewrite 500.52: Unrecognized element 'serverVariables'

Tags: iis-7, reverse-proxy, url-rewrite-module

I need to implement a reverse proxy using only my web.config and I'm having trouble with the 500.52 error. As suggested in many places online, I added the serverVariables section to include the HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING variable, but I am met with an error:

**Config Error**       Unrecognized element 'serverVariables'

Below is my web.config.

```
<rewrite>
      <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" />
    </allowedServerVariables>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="reverseProxy">
          <match pattern="http://linkInCode.com"></match>
          <serverVariables>
            <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
          </serverVariables>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="https://linkIWant.com/script.js"></action>
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

What is the problem? ServerVariables should be a recognised element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-part-2-dealing-with-500-52-status-codes/), I copied the examples given and changed sections for my needs.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
            <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://URLtoHide.com" />
        </rule>
</rules>
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to clean URL" preCondition="IsHTML">
        <match filterByTags="A" pattern="http://http://URLtoShow.com" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="https://URLtoHide.com" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="IsHTML">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the server variable registered previously in `<allowedServerVariables>`,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Allowed_Server_Variables_List